# Declare variable with unknown type

Tags: c++

I am reading .wav files in a c++ program.

The .wav format is such that a samples are either `uint8_t` or `int16_t`.  Is it possible to declare the variable based on the format of the specific file?

One solution would be:

```
int16_t sample;
if (bits==8)
{
  uint8_t temp8;
  in.read((char*)&temp8,bits);
  sample = (int16_t) temp8;
}
else
{
  in.read((char*)&sample,bits);
}
```

and I can use `sample` from now on. However that doesn't seem very handy and in the 8bit case the variable `sample` is bigger then it's needed.

I believe this could also be done with union but it still would make the variable take up 2 bytes regardless of anything.

What I would actually want is:

```
if(bits==8)
  uint8_t sample;
else
  int16_t sample;
```

But with a scope that exceeds the conditional statement.

Comment: You could make it a templated function

Comment: @dutt template are resolved at compilation, so definetly no.

Comment: or use void pointers if you are old school

Comment: Your original solution seems best to me

Comment: @remudada void pointers seem to offer a fun solution, but it seems quite limited with pointer arithmetics and arrays, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an abstract base class and a template class to provide different implementations of sample reader. Using the abstract interface, later code doesn't need to know if it handles 8 bit or 16 bit samples.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

class SampleReader
{
public:
    virtual void readSample( std::ifstream &in ) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class SampleReaderT : public SampleReader
{
public:
    virtual void readSample( std::ifstream &in )
    {
        while (!in.eof()) {
            const T value = readOneValue(in);
            if (in) {
                _sample.push_back();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    T readOneValue( std::ifstream &in )
    {
        T inputUnit;
        in.read((char*)&inputUnit,sizeof(T));
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _sample;
};

typedef SampleReaderT<int8_t> SampleReader8Bit;
typedef SampleReaderT<int16_t> SampleReader16Bit;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sampleBits = 8;

    SampleReader *sampleReader = nullptr;
    if (sampleBits == 8) {
        sampleReader = new SampleReader8Bit();
    } else if (sampleBits == 16) {
        sampleReader = new SampleReader16Bit();
    } else {
        throw std::out_of_range("unknown bit number");
    }

    std::ifstream in("test.dat");
    sampleReader->readSample(in);
}
```

Note the following things in this example:

- This is just an **example**, you certainly need to find a better design for your project.
- There is a base class with pure virtual methods. This base class is a great help to make your code abstract. You just can use a pointer to `SampleReader` and don't have to know if this is a 8bit or 16bit sample reader.
- The shown way to read the values is **not platform independent**. There are platforms with a different byte order.
- The error handling is missing in this example. Reading a stream can raise errors at any time.

Comment: The `while(!eof)` idiom ends up pushing one garbage character at the end; instead you need to test on the read operation. And `readOneValue` needs a `return` statement. (I realize this is just a hasty example, but if OP copies your code he may overlook these things)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! If you're going to correct the example according to Matt you might also want to correct uint16_t - 16bit wav samples are not unsigned. I will accept this if nobody comes with a shorter and more elegant solution.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are absolutely right. I added a test for this case in the example. The shown code should always be exemplary as good as possible.

Comment: @Juris I changed the types to signed ones. Please note this is just an example, you should put some time in a good design. The basic principle here is the *use of an interface* to *hide implementation details*.

Comment: @Flovdis, at first I thought that its needless correct you again, but I am starting to have a little doubt - the fact is that 8bit is unsigned, but 16bit samples are signed. If I set the correct types in the typedefs, will arithmetics be okay for either type or I have to typecast in arithmetic expressions?

Comment: (Of course I will test the behaviour, but knowing that it works in general is better than knowing that it works on some examples.)

Comment: @Juris If you write abstract code with implementations like this you can use every type which can be read from a file. You could also add a version which is reading floating point values. If the format doesn't match, just write specialised subclasses which reimplement e.g. the `readOneValue` method (make it protected, virtual first).